# Apache Derby master/slave replication and clustering

Tags: apache-2.2, replication, cluster, master-slave

I'm interested in the possibilities of master/slave replication for Derby in client/server mode (if at all possible). However, I'm unable to find any material that either explains it in a decent fashion or is able to convince me that master/slave replication doesn't exist for Derby.

Any pointers to decent reading material are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is quite old, but as it's still unanswered, here is a link to some information about derby replication:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/adminguide/cadminreplication.html

Note, that there is no automatic failover or restart of replication after one of the instances has failed.